# Single colon in JavaScript as a prefix to a variable (not object literal)

Tags: javascript, syntax

In Chrome you can do:

```
date = new Date();
```

and then in the console you can do:

```
hour:date.getHours();
```

What is this called? Where else does it work?

I saw this in the follow code:

```
showDateTimePicker(date, callback) {
    date = date || new Date();
    var options = {
        ...this.props,
        year:date.getFullYear(),
        month:date.getMonth(),
        day:date.getDate(),
        hour:date.getHours(),
        minute:date.getMinutes()
    };
    RCTDateTimePicker.showDateTimePicker(options, function (year, month, day, hour, minute) {
        date.setFullYear(year);
        date.setMonth(month);
        date.setDate(day);
        date.setHours(hour);
        date.setMinutes(minute);
        callback(date);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hour:date.getHours();` and `var options = {hour:date.getHours()};` are two very different statements.

The former is [a label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) which is designed so that when you have *nested* loops and want to `break` or `continue` from one of them, you can specify which. Putting it before a function call is useless.

The latter is [an object initialiser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Creating_objects) which allows you to specify the name and values of properties on a new object.

Comment: wowza, I must have been up waaay too late or something. for some reason the lack of spaces on either side of the colon had me thinking it was a whole different concept. That and I was fresh off looking at android XML which had something like  android:timePickerMode="spinner"